# Move ISPConfig 3 site from one server to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I feel this must be something other people have had to do before me but I can't find anything useful anywhere on this topic. I've inherited an ISPConfig 3 server with a number of sites spread across 2 separate servers. I want to rationalise the setup so that there is only one server.

Moving the files for a site from one server seems straightforward enough, simply zipping up the files and then SCPing them across. Fine. But how do I change the configuration in the ISPConfig control panel? "Server" isn't editable, and it won't let me create another site with the same domain as an existing entry.

Does anyone know of any documentation for this? I really can't be the first person to want to move sites across servers! I've found some people who've migrated an entire ISPConfig server with multiple sites from one machine to another in one fell swoop, but that's not what I'm after; I want to move individual sites from one server to another. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you just take the opportunity to ditch the GUI?

Comment: In the long term I might be tempted to lose ISPConfig and replace it with something more streamlined, such as WHM/cPanel, but in the short term that's not really an option.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Comment: @HopelessN00b To be fair, ISPConfig basically just sits on top of a standard Apache install.  When you change a setting in the GUI, it simply modifies the relevant file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` using a cron job (runs every minute as root to make the changes).  I use ISPConfig to manage a few dozen sites over several clients, because it's less of a headache, but I also SSH in to change things.